# Pass parameters to PHP on subdomain with htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I have a domain (example.com) with WordPress running on it and a subdomain (u.example.com) that does not. The files for the subdomain are stored at example.com/u. I am trying to pass parameters to my subdomain using slashes. For example: `u.example.com/sometext` would be processed by `u.example.com/index.php?par=sometext`. I have been searching and trying different things, but I cannot get it to work with the subdomain.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^u\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\/? u\/index.php?par=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: 500 is just a generic error code that essentially means "something went wrong". You will need to check your apache log files to see what actually happened. You also haven't given us any code, so we can't exactly help you.

Comment: Apologies, I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^u\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\/? \/index.php?par=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Originally it would send me into an infinite loop so `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php` was added to prevent that.